# VueJS || Добавить Object в Object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

По клике на кнопку необходимо в Object добавить Object.Поясняю что необходимо:
Имею [Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLrAb.png) , который выглядит как структура разделов ( развернутый [Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PelA.png)). Из данного Object вытягиваю данные в select. Необходимо при клике на кнопку **Добавить еще** в данный Object скопировать полностью его 0 элемент. Т.е что должно [получится](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fluD1.png) . Прошу посодействовать в решении данного вопроса, примеры,ссылки, документация функций или методов через чего можно обвернуть это все. Если необходимо уточнить какие то вопросы, задавайте.

Comment: Разместите код здесь, а не на картинках

Comment: Пожалуйста, разместил

Answer (score -1):

На js можно решить через Object.assign();
Если для VueJs нужна реактивность , то this.$set - [документация](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)